# List view in a stub goes black when dragged.

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm making an app that has a bunch of buttons at the bottom and a bunch of ViewStubs at the top. All the buttons point to one listener and that listener switches between the buttons id to decide on which stub to inflate. 
So if button 1 is clicked, any previous stub loading is undone and stub 1 is inflated.

Now, on stub 4, I need a list view but there seems to be a problem when I drag the list.

The issue I'm having is that the list view goes black when I drag it.

Here is the code:
package com.me.myapp;
MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewStub;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int stubNum;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (savedInstanceState  == null) {
            doStuff((View) findViewById(R.id.button1));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt("stubNum", stubNum);
        Log.d("Jason", "Saving stubNum is " + stubNum);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        stubNum = savedInstanceState.getInt("stubNum");
        Log.d("Jason", "Saved stubNum is " + stubNum);
        if (findViewById(stubNum) != null)
        {
            ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(stubNum);
            View newView = stub.inflate();
            Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
            button1.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);

            Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
            button2.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    // Implement the OnClickListener callback
    public void doStuff(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                try
                {
                    stubNum = 1;
                    ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub1);
                    if (!(stub.getVisibility() == ViewStub.VISIBLE)) {
                        View newView = stub.inflate();
                        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
                        button1.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);

                        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
                        button2.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    stubNum = stub.getId();
                    Log.d("Jason", "stubNum is " + stubNum);
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                try
                {
                    stubNum = 2;
                    ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub2);
                    if (!(stub.getVisibility() == ViewStub.VISIBLE)) {
                        View newView = stub.inflate();
                        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
                        button1.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);

                        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
                        button2.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    stubNum = stub.getId();
                    Log.d("Jason", "stubNum is " + stubNum);
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                try
                {
                    stubNum = 3;
                    ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub3);
                    if (!(stub.getVisibility() == ViewStub.VISIBLE)) {
                        View newView = stub.inflate();
                        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
                        button1.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);

                        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
                        button2.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    stubNum = stub.getId();
                    Log.d("Jason", "stubNum is " + stubNum);
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                try
                {
                    stubNum = 4;
                    ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub4);            
                    if (!(stub.getVisibility() == ViewStub.VISIBLE)) {
                        View newView = stub.inflate();
                        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
                        button1.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);

                        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
                        button2.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    stubNum = stub.getId();
                    Log.d("Jason", "stubNum is " + stubNum);


                }
                catch(NullPointerException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button5:
                try
                {
                    stubNum = 5;
                    ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub5);
                    if (!(stub.getVisibility() == ViewStub.VISIBLE)) {
                        View newView = stub.inflate();
                        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
                        button1.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);

                        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
                        button2.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    stubNum = stub.getId();
                    Log.d("Jason", "stubNum is " + stubNum);
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:
                stubNum = 1;
                ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub1);
                if (!(stub.getVisibility() == ViewStub.VISIBLE)) {
                    View newView = stub.inflate();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/download" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_margin="2dip" android:onClick="doStuff"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/download" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_margin="2dip" android:onClick="doStuff"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/download" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_margin="2dip" android:onClick="doStuff"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/download" android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_margin="2dip" android:onClick="doStuff"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/download" android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_margin="2dip" android:onClick="doStuff"></ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3">
        <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub1"
               android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
               android:layout="@layout/myvarsity"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub2"
               android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
               android:layout="@layout/livestream"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub3"
               android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
               android:layout="@layout/shows"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub4"
               android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
               android:layout="@layout/more"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub5"
               android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
               android:layout="@layout/settings"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:text="Customize" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:text="Back" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="App" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

more.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/moreList"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Morelistview" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

more_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/moreItem" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android:cacheColorHint = "#00000000"
```

use this tag for the your listView. or you can also use

```
listview.setCacheColorHint()
```

to set it programatically.

Comment: Many thanks, Mr Kumar! I've also got an issue with my orientation change but I'll be working through that. Thanks for your time!!